# FileReader javascript class not working with IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using javascript FileReader class to preview the image prior to uploading it to the server. Everything seems to work fine with Firefox and Chrome but it does not seem to work with IE for some reason.

Below is my code for it. (This is for Cakephp framework)

Is there a way we can fix this so it works in IE too?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function imageBack(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#uploadBackImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    $('#cardbackImagePath').attr('value',e.target.result);
                }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }
        </script>
<input type="file" name="data[Card][uploadBack]" class="file" onchange="imageBack(this);" width="240" height="150" id="CardUploadBack">
```

Comment: IE is a bit vague. What version of IE are you having trouble with?

Comment: Because IE is not a browser o/ If its IE < 9 dont even think about FileRader

Comment: IE isn't expected to get support for the **draft** FileReader spec until version 10: http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In IE you should use [ActiveXObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because IE is not a browser

Comment: Thanks for your answer Norbert, is there a good example of using ActiveXObject and Javascript for this purposes of image previewing?

Comment: Norberg, nice remark "IE IS NOT A BROWSER" ;) I realy agree with you! +1

Answer (score 1):

FileReader is a relatively new addition to JavaScript and because Internet Explorer is old it doesn't support it yet. Internet Explorer 7/8 doesn't support it at all and IE9 only has partial support for offline storage. Internet Explorer 10, however, is going to get early support. I would just stick a message on there for IE users telling them (politely, of course) to get a real browser.